# How to fix password related issue in mysql

Tags: mysql

While setting up password for mysql i used the wrong code

```
update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD=('password') where user='root';
```

Here PASSWORD has been set to a value which i am not able to identify .I have tried safe mode recovery too,but the problem is not being solved.How to rectify this?

I have tried safe mode recovery,but there also the old password was required.

Answer (score 0):

We can work this out by reproducing the problem in a toy example:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (Bar TEXT);
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES("Hello world");
SELECT * FROM Foo;
UPDATE Foo SET Bar=BAR=('password');
SELECT * FROM Foo;
```

#### ([live demo](https://paiza.io/projects/lnolqmcf0cgDQlUnyD8DUw?language=mysql))

The first `SELECT` shows us `Hello world`; the second shows us `0`. So, for whatever reason, the mistaken expression `BAR=('password')` resulted in `0`. Therefore I believe the *hash* of your password is `0`.

Trouble is, this doesn't really help you, because you'd need to know the password that maps to said hash — and it's likely that *there isn't one*.

You should just reset the root password, by spinning up the server with the `--skip-grant-tables` switch (disabling auth checks), then log in and set your password properly ([ref](https://www.a2hosting.co.uk/kb/developer-corner/mysql/reset-mysql-root-password)). Be sure to restart it in "normal" mode afterwards, because that switch is dangerous! In fact, I suggest closing your firewall to incoming MySQL connections for the duration of the task.

Comment: I tried resetting the root password ,but again there a prompt appears asking for root pasword.

Comment: @nishantgautam Did you restart the server with the `--skip-grant-tables` switch like I said?